# Unable to convert cursor to array Node.js & MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to count the number of all documents in a collection ( I know I just can use `collection.count()` but I want to get all documents for further operations). Here is my attempt :

```
collection.find({},function(err, doc)
 {
   if(err)
   {
    console.log(err)
   }
   console.log(doc); //using this I can see the cursor

  doc.toArray(function(errx, docx)
  {
    if(errx)
    {
      console.log(errx);
    }
    console.log(docx.length);
  });

 });
```

The code displays the content of the cursor but it does not show anything about the array. Can you tell me which step is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#find):

```
collection.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
  console.log(doc.length);
});
```

Comment: I got this : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toArray' of undefined`

Comment: makes no sense to me. could you provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: What makes the least sense is the OP keeps duplicating their question rather than addressing the people who already provided answers for it.

Comment: @NeilLunn Which part of the question resembles the previous one?

Comment: @jason All of it. You have now asked the same thing three times. It all relates to "getting the result from find" and all because of trying to read from a cursor as a single element. Also there is only one place where you actually mention you are in fact using "monk". The overall point being there are presently 5 answers sitting on the question where you has not bothered to confirm problems to the people who bothered to answer. Deal with the people there please. And don't post the same question again.

Comment: I'm trying mongoose with the code in this question. I suspect there is a problem with MongoDB

Comment: @jason, sorry, didn't realise it is mongoose. The answer is for the native driver. Please add a reproducible example to the question to avoid further confusion.

Comment: @AlexBlex finally I can get some results using `.forEach()`. But `toArray()` keeps me waiting. Is that normal?

Comment: `.forEach()` works with cursor fetching one frame at a time. `toArray()` returns all documents from your collection. If it is big enough it may take time, or even kill your node app.

Comment: @AlexBlex It was supposed to bring about 700 documents.  Could you give a few hints on getting data faster from Mongo? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The question just don't have enough information to advise anything sensible.

Comment: I'm just doing the query in your answer. Nothing complex.

Comment: Once again, the query in the answer is for native driver, not for mongoose, or any other abstraction on top of it. It does not address any performance issues, but answers the question 'convert cursor to array' stated in the title.